# Trouble accessing ColumnDescription from Google DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, database, datatable

I am working on a project where I am interacting with a google datatable object. I want to find the names for each column in the datatable. I tried the following and got the following firebug error:

tile.Table.getAllColumnIds is not a function

```
    function accessColumns (group) {

        var count = group.Table.getNumberOfColumns();
        var i=0;
        for (i=0;i<=count;i++)
        {
            alert(i);
            var ColumnDescription = group.Table.getColumnDescription(i);
            alert (ColumnDescription.getLabel());
        }
    }
```

The part that makes this confusing is that the getNumberOfColumns() works correctly and gives me  the number 6. But when I enter the for loop it crashes saying getColumnDescription is not a function. How can one method work but the other not work?

I am working from the following API chart:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/ColumnDescription.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can use DataView methods with DataTable objects but you cannot use DataTable methods with DataTables. I double checked and I am in fact using a DataTable. This is isn't exactly a solution, but if you experience this problem try this work around.